# How to perform oauth with Nextjs and external REST API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-oauth, nestjs

I am making an application with Nextjs and Nestjs for API. I want to support server-side rendering for certain pages with Nextjs. The authentication and user registrations need to be done on Nestjs. For now I am trying to do google oauth.

For requests from client side to API, I will have to send some access token along with the request to authorize the user. And for server-side authorization, I'll have to get this access token from the cookies and then send it in the request to the API. From what I have seen, access tokens last only 1 hour. So how can I do it in a way that lasts longer than 1 hour?